# Linking Ghostscript to pypdfocr in Windows Platform

Tags: windows, python-2.7, linker, ocr, anaconda

Installed pypdfocr and ghostscript via pip installation. But, when the pypdfocr is run in the command prompt:

```
[env27] C:\Users\888537>pypdfocr Hotel.pdf
ERROR: Could not find Ghostscript in the usual place; please specify it using your config file
```

Requesting for help as to what needs to be done to link these libraries?

Answer (score 5):

You can install Ghostscript directly via installer given on their page - https://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

After that, you need to set environment variable.

Add a new system variable:

**Variable:** GS_PROG

**Value:**  Full path to the location of your gswin64c.exe file (in your GhostScript installation directory – the default location is C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64c.exe, but this may vary depending on where you installed it)