# Wand Policy Error: error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412

Tags: python-3.x, wand

I am facing the issue while converting pdf to image using Wand:

```
E           wand.exceptions.PolicyError: not authorized `/opt/sample.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412
```

I have already visited the previous stack overflow question here:
[convert:not authorized `aaaa` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453)

Here is my code

```
def build_image(self, pdf_path, img_path):
    with wand.image.Image(filename=pdf_path) as img:
        img.save(filename=img_path)
```

My code was working from last 6 months. Now, why am I getting this error?

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert:not authorized \`aaaa\` @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is probably due to an security fix of the underlaying package (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1796563)

I fixed it for me by editing the /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml and changed the rights for the pdf line to "read":

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF" />
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. However, I need to login as super user to edit the policy.xml file which is present under /home/xxx/etc/ImageMagick-6/

Comment: this fixed the issue, don't forget to restart apache.

Comment: If you are using jupyter notebook you need to restart the server Ctrl-C and run it again

Comment: Command to do this: `sed -i 's,<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />,<policy domain="coder" rights="read" pattern="PDF" />,g' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Troubleshooting ImageMagick on Debian-based systems.

If encountered with a PolicyError, you may be able to fix it by changing the following line in /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml from this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
```

to this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

(More details about policy.xml available [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php).)

Taken from the [repo](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#troubleshooting-imagemagick-on-debian-based-systems)

Answer (score 2):

Editing the /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml and changed the rights for the pdf line to "read|write":

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

and restarting the server in my case Jupiter Notebook runtime fixed my issue