# when i run the below code to convert pdf image to jpg policy error popped up

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, magickwand

```
import os
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi
import gc

pdfim=wi(filename="salem-father.pdf",resolution=300)
```

> PolicyError: not authorized `salem-father.pdf' @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412

Comment: Structure code and citation block

Comment: there are many other ways to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wand Policy Error: error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699608/wand-policy-error-error-constitute-c-readimage-412)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert or  extract images from pdf file to jpg or its format using below code.

requirements.txt :

```
PyMuPDF==1.16.5
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.12.0
```

code:

```
import fitz
import random, string

doc = "mypdf.pdf" # path to pdf file
doc = fitz.open(doc)
pno = doc.loadPage(4) # enter the page
text = pno.getText('dict')# dict format of the file
blocks = text["blocks"]
imgblocks = [b for b in blocks if b["type"] == 1]

x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + 
string.digits) for _ in range(16))

if imgblocks:
   for index, img in enumerate(imgblocks):
       img_name1 = "%s-%s.%s" % (x, index, img['ext']) # png
       img_name2 = "%s-%s.jpg" % (x, index) # jpg
       with open(img_name1, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img['image'])

       with open(img_name2, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(img['image'])
```