# PDF to text in Python returning empty results in image files

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, pdf-extraction

I've got this [scanned pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DTGkr1ltsgMDChYVgb8KSCWYbgcQFPVV/view?usp=sharing). Image based low resolution pdf file. I'm trying to extract the data in it and all options I've tried seem not to work.

**Option 1 - using pdfminer**

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
```

**Option 2 - using tika**

```
from tika import parser # pip install tika
raw = parser.from_file(path)
text=raw['content']
# I don't like to use it very much because it often corrupts the file
```

**Option 3 - using pypdf**

```
    import PyPDF2
    pdf_file = open(path, 'rb')
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    text=page_content.encode('utf-8')
```

All the options return empty results. I suppose it might be related to the quality of the file.
I know we could work on images and increase image characteristics to ease the data extraction (increase image size, work on thresholds, etc, you can do a lot of stuff with PIL). Is there an efficient way to also do that with pdf files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I came up with a solution which is not ideal but worked for me using pdfminer and pytesseract:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

def convert_pdf_image_to_text(file_path):
    from pdf2image import convert_from_path
    import pytesseract

    dpi = 350 # dots per inch
    pages = convert_from_path(file_path ,dpi)
    text=""

    for i in range(len(pages)):
        page = pages[i]
        a=pytesseract.image_to_string(page)
        text=text+a

    return text

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()

# extracting data from image pdfs

if "a" not in text or "A" not in text and extract_image_pdfs==True:
    # my pdfs will always have an "a" that's why I use this if sentence above
    try:
        print('starting to convert to image')
        text=convert_pdf_image_to_text(path)
        print('finished converting to image')
    except:
        text="no text"
        print("not pdf nor image")

return text
```

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever tried extracting texts non scanned pdfs, and I remember pdfminer giving the best results.
However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480280/convert-scanned-pdf-to-text-python)! might help you, also there are some other OCR python libraries for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

pypdf, tika, and pdfminer are not OCR libraries and thus will never be able to convert images into text.

It does not matter that the image is embedded in a PDF document. It's just not the type of problem those libraries deal with. They can extract the included images, but not the text within the images.

Think of PDF in a similar way to ZIP files. You would not expect WinZIP to be able to extract text from images, just because the images are within a ZIP file.

What you need is OCR (Optical Character Recognition) software. Tesseract is likely the most famous example in the open source world. ABBYY FineReader is a commercial product.